# How to eliminate a combo box from a form

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following form with a " select " tag :

```
  <form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <br>Filename:&nbsp;<input name="userfile" type="file">
  <p>Customer:&nbsp;      


  <select name="customer">

  <?php
include 'data.dat';
include 'error.inc';

// Connect to the database
if (!($connection = @ mysql_connect ($hostName,
                                    $username,
                                    $password)))

die ("Could not connect to database");

// Select the database
if (!mysql_select_db ($databaseName, $connection))
    showerror();

// Display all the available customers in order
$query = "SELECT customer FROM custlist order by id";

if (!($result = @ mysql_query ($query, $connection)))
    showerror();

$i = 0;

// Display each customer in a drop down menu. 
while ($row = @ mysql_fetch_array ($result))
{
    $i++;
    if ($i == 1)
        echo "<option value=" . $i . " selected>" . $row['customer'] . "\n";
    else
        echo "<option value=" . $i . ">" . $row['customer'] . "\n";
  //
}
  //


  ?>

  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload file">
  </form>
```

As the database has only 1 row with only one customer i wish to eliminate the combo box and select automatically the only one customer. How can i do this? I'm really a newbie and after a lot of modifies i still not found the solution.

Thanks for your help.

Mat

**UPDATES**

Thanks to some suggestion i'm working on this modifies... still doesn't work but i think is the right way, isn't it?

Here is the code:

```
  <select name="customer">

  <?php
include 'data.dat';
include 'error.inc';

// Connect to the database
if (!($connection = @ mysql_connect ($hostName,
                                    $username,
                                    $password)))

die ("Could not connect to database");

// Select the log database
if (!mysql_select_db ($databaseName, $connection))
    showerror();

// Display all the available customers in order
$query = "SELECT customer FROM curlist order by id";

  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
  echo  $row['customer'];


  ?>

  </select>
```

Comment: Store all the results from the database into an array.  If the array is only 1 element long, then do blah, if it's more than 1 element long, do bleh.  Too broad of question for anyone to post code helping you.

Answer (score 3):

As per suggestion, am posting my stab at it as an answer:

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count == 1) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo '<input type="text" value="' . htmlentities($row['customer']) . '" readonly />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="customer" value="..." />';
} else {
    echo '<select name="customer">';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<option value="...">' . htmlentities($row['customer']) . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
```

The ... in the value would ideally be some kind of primary key in the table.

Comment: I suggest to add the readonly attribute to the text input element.

Answer (score 0):

After the call to `mysql_query`, you should call `mysql_num_rows()` to find out how many rows were returned from your SELECT statement, and if 1, proceed without displaying the select.

Comment: By the way, most of what I write is a direct quote from the PHP documentation for that function: [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php).

Comment: Edited my answer to answer that.

Comment: Watch the updates on my answer window, am I following the right way?

Answer (score 0):

You can't eliminate a combo box that is hard coded into the HTML structure.

Incorporate this HTML into your code using something like:

```
// Get number of rows returned by query
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

// Start iteration counter
$i = 1; # start at one to marry up with $count

// Iterate through array of mySQL rows
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    if ($count == 1) {  # Evals true if 1 customer is returned
        $html = "<input type=\"textbox\" value=\"". $row['customer'] . "\" />";

    // If multiple customers are returned, 
    // but it's the first iteration through the loop. Create Select box.
    } elseif ($i == 1 && $count != 1) { 

        $html .= "<select name=\"customer\">\n";
        $html .= "<option value=\"" . $row['id'] . "\">" . $row['customer'] . "</option>\n";

    // If this is the last row, close the select box.
    } elseif ($i == $count) {
        // 
        $html .= "<option value=\"" . $row['id'] . "\">" . $row['customer'] . "</option>\n";
        $html .= "</select>\n";

    // If none of the above, create new option
    } else {
        $html .= "<option value=\"" . $row['id'] . "\">" . $row['customer'] . "</option>\n";
    }

    $i++;
}

echo $html;
```

EDIT: From comments below, changed the `<option>` value attribute to be the customers row ID.

Comment: That code could be made much cleaner by handling the if clauses outside of the loop.  Also, you could do the <select> tags before and after the loop.

Comment: You could certainly move the first two clauses out of the loop. Wrote this quick and dirty :) + wanted something that made semantic sense to someone new to php and grouping the conditional statements was part of this.

Comment: To me, it's more confusing.  Guess that's just personal preference though.  One thing though is that the $i could end up being useless since primary key might not be ascending and contiguous.  The $i is required though if the clauses are inside the while.

Comment: Well shifting the statements outside would require further SQL evaluation for one, makes sense to keep it all together. And I think you're getting confused with your arrays. $count will always be the total number of rows returned... primary keys?. $i therefore as a counter for the while loop is required.

Comment: Would not require further SQL evaluation.  You're already using mysql_num_rows.  And you're using $i for the value of the option...  Basically you're assuming $i will uniquely map to that row in a useful manner.  One second and I'll post the code I would do somewhere.

Comment: Ohh I see what you mean re: $i. That was an oversite on my part. Would be better to have that as $row['id'] without doubt. $i would still be needed to calculate the last iteration of the while loop mind you.

Comment: Post it as an answer Corbin, it's far more elegant than the above!

Comment: I'm working on a modified code that doesn't seem to work yet but I see it very simple. I need just to read the customner name to send in the form and necessary for the update.php execution. Am I wrong in something?

Comment: Customer names can be duplicated.  You should be depending on some kind of customer id that is unique to each unique person.  Names are not unique.

Comment: Well but the system has been modified so that customer will be always unique... i think i just need to read that value for the form needs